# The topological manifold of the space of full rank $M(m\times n,R)$ is connected

Tags: algebraic-geometry, manifolds

I was wondering if there is a proof that the space of full rank matrices $M(m\times n,R)$ with $m<n$ is a connected space using algebraic geometry.

One can construct $n \choose m$ equations by taking a the determinant of each $m \times m$ submatrix of an element of $M(m\times n,R)$.

If we allow an unknown for each entry in $M(m\times n,R)$, then we end up with $n \choose m$ equations with $m\times n$ unknowns with the zeroes being all the less than full rank matrices.

Is there somehow we can use algebraic geometry to then show the full rank matrices are connected?

Comment: Perhaps overkill, but did you try to use induction and some fibrations?

Comment: (Whoops, didn't read the requirement to use algebraic geometry.)

Answer (score 1):

If you can compute the global functions on this variety, you can tell whether it's connected or not. Recall that if $X=\bigcup_{i}X_i$ is a disconnected algebraic variety with finitely many connected components $X_i$, then $k[X]=\bigoplus_{i}k[X_i]$. So if you can't decompose $k[X]$ into a direct sum of subrings, then your variety is connected. The easiest place to demonstrate you can't do that is with constant functions.

Comment: Thanks for this. As my knowledge of algebraic geometry is a bit limited it will take me some time to digest this answer.